# Minecraft installer can't detect Oracle Java

Tags: installation, java, arch-linux, minecraft

I am having this strange problem with installing the Minecraft launcher on Arch Linux.

So I installed the Oracle JDK in the `/usr/lib/jvm` directory, updated `$PATH` to add `$JAVA_HOME` and the next step was to install the MC launcher using AUR.

I `git clone` the repo and do `makeinstall -si` on the directory and it requires that I install openjdk.

I don't understand why it can't find the java version that I installed (maybe the path it's searching in is not `/usr/bin/jvm`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, rather than installing java directly, use AUR.